# How to call a service method with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

As we can call service method in a jsp as follow(say to check authorization) :

```
<sec:authorize var="hasLicense" access="@licenseService.hasCapability('Event')"/>
```

How can we call this method when using Thymeleaf?

I know, We can check role as follow but couldn't get an example for above case:

```
<li class="link" sec:authorize="hasRole('event')">
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Thymeleaf allows accessing beans registered at the Spring Application
>   Context with the @beanName syntax, for example:
>
> ```
> <div th:text="${@urlService.getApplicationUrl()}">...</div>
> ```

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

So this should work:

```
<li class="link" sec:authorize="${@licenseService.hasCapability('Event')}">
```

Answer (score 4):

For you to call your service methods from your `Thymeleaf` template you need to add that service into your model like so

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @Autowired
    LicenseService licenseService;

    @RequestMapping("/yourPage")
    public String getYourPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("licenseService", licenseService);
        return "yourPage.html";
    }

}
```

After that you are good to use `licenseService` in `yourPage.html`.

```
<div th:if="${licenseService.verifyLicense() == true}">
    <p> License verified </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdullah!! it works that way. But is this fine to add service to model?  Can't we do something with sec:authorize to achieve this?

Comment: You just opened a new world for me! Thank you.