# How to call a @Service bean from Thymeleaf under Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a bean that is defined as a service:

```
@Service
public class FileHandling {
  public void doSomething() {
...
```

It's possible to autowire it in my app and use it:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fileHandling")
FileHandling fh;
```

When I try to use it in a Thymeleaf template I receive this error message:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:
>   No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean
>   'fileHandling'

This is the relevant part of my template:

```
<td th:text="${@fileHandling.doSomething()}">...</td>
```

This is how I access the templating engine:

```
final Context ctx = new Context();
ctx.setVariable("files", map);
ctx.setVariable("fileHandling",fh);

String html = templateEngine.process("flattopic", ctx);
```

I receive the error message no matter if I try to access the bean directly or after `setVariable("fileHandling")`. The syntax I use complies to what I see in chapter 5 of https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html.

I've seen similar questions which apply to basic SPEL (this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328124/no-bean-resolver-registered-in-the-context-to-resolve-access-to-bean)) or an [unanswered](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/EL1057E-No-bean-resolver-registered-in-the-context-to-resolve-access-to-bean-td4028372.html) question specific to Thymeleaf.
The alternative to switch from a bean to a static class and 
 use `${T(org.foo.bar.package.FileHandling).doSomething()}` is something that I would like to avoid.

How can I solve this or make the bean accessible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a service method with Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841458/how-to-call-a-service-method-with-thymeleaf)

Comment: @bphilipnyc Thanks for the link, but I think that my problem is different (see my edit)

Comment: @Marged the difference is that you are not defining a service on the application context

Comment: @cralfaro You mean that the bean I define with Service and that I can wire in anywhere else successfully is not visible to Thymeleafs context ? How would I achieve this ?

Comment: @Marged exactly, you need to define the service in a Configuration class, then on startup the service will be loadad in your app context and you can use it from thymeleaf or whatever

Answer (score 6):

"Call a bean from Thymeleaf under Spring Boot" is also "Call a bean from Thymeleaf under Spring MVC". For example:

Interface

```
package com.example;

public interface UrlService {

    String getApplicationUrl();

}
```

You has component `MyConfiguration`

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "urlService")
    public UrlService urlService() {
        return () -> "domain.com/myapp";
    }

}
```

In Thymeleaf template file `foo.html`

```
<div th:text="${@urlService.getApplicationUrl()}">...</div>
```

Source: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html#spring-beans

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see where my code is different / which changes I have to make

Comment: @Marged, if you think the answer was helpful, click the upvote button :)

Comment: I have do the same thing but it's not working
EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean

Answer (score 1):

Simply by declaring the `@Service` it should give the bean the name `fileHandling`.

```java
@Service
public class FileHandling {
  public void doSomething() {
```

You can override it [like this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming):

```java
@Service("someOtherName")
public class FileHandling {
  public void doSomething() {
```

Make sure you have [enabled autoconfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.auto-configuration).

Read more information in Baeldung [Spring Bean Names](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-names).